# C4714 as an error in CLI project, Release only

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, clr, compiler-warnings

I have a __forceinline function that cannot be inlined when compiled as CLI (probably due to the specific restrictions to inlining that apply with .NET).

In debug, it is a warning and does not prevent me from building. But in release, it comes up as an error:

```
error C4714: function '...' marked as __forceinline not inlined
```

In the project configuration, `Treat Warnings As Errors` is set to `No (/WX-)`, `Treat Specific Warnings As Errors` is empty (no value and no inherited value) and there is no `/We` option in the Command Line of the `C/C++` section.

Thus, I don't understand why this warning comes up as an error.
And as it is an error it prevents me from building the project in release.

- Do you have any clue on why this comes up as an error?
- Any idea of how I could get rid of it, considering I cannot change the function nor its use (it comes from a library I'm using and I'd like not to alter)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: (1) Double check that Configuration-Platform pair (e.g. Release-x64) is actually the same as the one that you are building. Compiler options in VS are set for every pair separately. (2) Otherwise, inspect the project files (e.g. .vcproj) with a text editor to find what's going on. (3) Try to use `msbuild` directly from command line. (4) Check that there are no `#pragma` statements that change compiler settings somewhere above this function (you may need to inspect the output of the preprocessor).

Comment: (5) if no success, create a new minimal project with a `__forceinline`. Make sure it builds. Then replace old project files with this one and add relevant files and settings gradually, until bug manifests. This way you can find the offending part.

Comment: @Drop Thank you very much for you help! I checked (1), (2), (3) - getting the same errors with no additional information even with verbosity set very high -, (4) - no #pragma -. I'm trying the (5) currently.

Comment: After outputing the preprocessor to a file I finally found the #pragma !

Comment: If you put your steps as Answer I would validate your answer as solution :)
Thank you very much !